# why PHP casting MySQL BIT(1) value b'0' to boolean 'true'

Tags: php, mysql, casting

I have a table in MySQL whose structure is as followed:

```
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(32)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| bit   | bit(1)           | NO   |     | b'0'    |                |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I insert a record as followed:

```
+----+-------------+-----+
| id | name        | bit |
+----+-------------+-----+
|  1 | john        |     |
+----+-------------+-----+
```

Then I use a PHP script to select it and the script is as followed:

```
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=Test", "username","password");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `for_test` WHERE `name` = :name";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute([':name' => 'john']);
    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
         var_dump((boolean)$row['bit']);
    }
```

I expect the output should be

```
bool(false)
```

However, the output is

```
bool(true)
```

Why is bit 0 casting to 'true'?

Comment: `var_dump($row['bit'])`

Comment: Why would you even call a column `bit`. That's like naming a dog `dog`.

Comment: Thanks @AbraCadaver. var_dump($row['bit']) output string(1) "". And var_dump(empty($row['bit'])) output bool(false) which means $rows['bit'] is non-empty or non-zero. So if  $row['bit'] is casting to boolean, it equals to 'TURE', because any non-zero value should be considered as 'true'. (Reference document PHP [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) ) . But I am curious to know how string(1) "" is stored.

Answer (score 0):

Look closely, and you'll notice `var_dump()`'s output says the string *length* is 1, *not* 0. It contains a single character, so it's not an empty string, hence `empty()` and other boolean comparisons evaluate it as `true`.

As for *what* is this character... surprisingly, at least PhP 5.4 and MySQL 5.5, it's the `NUL` character! Yes, ASCII 0, 0x00